# bootstrap card height and width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm having a problem with card at small devices  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyFVU.jpg)
, how can I set all card the same width ? that is work fine with large screen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIyPO.jpg).

my code at asp.net :

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptOrders" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" >
   <ItemTemplate>
      <div class=" col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 card text-center h-100 " style=" border-radius: 20px; border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);float: none!important; overflow:hidden;  "  >
         <h3>   <a href='Txxxx?id=<%#Eval("Id")%>'  > <%#Eval("Name")   %> </a></h3>
         <%#  getLang(Eval("Lang").ToString()) %>  
         <%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("Date").ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")%> -  <%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("StartTime").ToString()).ToString("hh:mm tt")%>
         <p> - Seats  <%# getPlace(int.Parse(Eval("Id").ToString()), Eval("Count").ToString()) %> </p>
         <p style="background-color:white!important"><%# getLink(int.Parse(Eval("Id").ToString())) %> 
            <a href='Details.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Id")%>'  style="background: #7accb240;"> details</a>
         </p>
      </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblEmptyData" runat="server" Visible='<%# ((Repeater)Container.NamingContainer).Items.Count == 0 %>' Text="yyy"></asp:Label>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: It seems like this question doesn't actually have anything to do with C#/ ASP.NET, so I removed those tags

Comment: You should put it inside a `<div class="row">` then bootstrap handles this automatically for you.

Comment: where put the div ?